# Code igniter 3.1.2 - disabling the cache not working

Tags: caching, codeigniter-3

I have configured a code igniter project on IIS. I am facing issue of cache. I want to disable the cache. But every method which i found is not disabling it. I have tried the following code in constructor:

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

But it is not help full.

It is updating cache after one minute. Can any one suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to opcache of php. I have commented out all the opcache lines from php.ini file. Now it is not caching the page.